# Lync Service does not allow a cross domain request from this origin

Tags: javascript, jquery, skype, skype-for-business

I am using ucwa skype api. I have downloaded sample from ucwa.skype.com. while running the sample I need to login to my skype for business account. It gives me the below error.

> jquery-1.6.2.min.js:17 GET http://lyncdiscoverinternal.ge.com/xframe
>   net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED(anonymous function) @
>   jquery-1.6.2.min.js:17domManip @ jquery-1.6.2.min.js:17domManip @
>   jquery.tmpl.min.js:1append @ jquery-1.6.2.min.js:17html @
>   jquery-1.6.2.min.js:17Transport.obj.injectFrame @
>   Transport.js:516startAutoDiscover @
>   AutoDiscovery.js:51AutoDiscovery.obj.startDiscovery @
>   AutoDiscovery.js:141beginDiscovery @ Index.js:91processAuthClick @
>   Index.js:101(anonymous function) @ Index.js:163handle @
>   jquery-1.6.2.min.js:17k @ jquery-1.6.2.min.js:16 Transport.js:479
>   Frame location not found within timeout (10000):
>   http://lyncdiscoverinternal.ge.com/xframe XFrame.js:143 GET
>   http://lyncdiscover.ge.com/xframe 403 (Forbidden)sendRequest @
>   XFrame.js:143(anonymous function) @ XFrame.js:207
>   scriptInjector.js:193 sI: inside WIDGET_CONTENT_MESSAGE message
>   listener: MessageEvent scriptInjector.js:194 MessageEvent
>   scriptInjector.js:193 sI: inside WIDGET_CONTENT_MESSAGE message
>   listener: MessageEvent scriptInjector.js:194 MessageEvent
>   Transport.js:186 Service does not allow a cross domain request from
>   this origin. AutoDiscovery.js:93 Autodiscovery failed on
>   internal/external location contentScript.js:234 cs:
>   onRequestListener(Arguments[3]) contentScript.js:234 cs:
>   onRequestListener(Arguments[3])

Answer (score 0):

This issue (Service does not allow a cross domain request from this origin.) is mostly caused by the "Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)" and that the address which is requesting the access isn´t "whitelisted".

An Skype for Business Administrator can configure that via (more info's [here](https://ucwa.skype.com/documentation/itadmin-configuration)):

```
$x = New-CsWebOrigin -Url "https://apps.contoso.com"
Set-CsWebServiceConfiguration -Identity "{YOUR_IDENTITY}" -CrossDomainAuthorizationList @{Add=$x}
```

before you change that, check if that is already done via:

```
Get-CsWebServiceConfiguration | select -ExpandProperty CrossDomainAuthorizationList
```

So that you will not overwrite something